# How to delete a group of shape keys? And how to set bone rotation to 0

Tags: transforms, shape-keys, transform-orientation

I'm fairly new to blender, and I've been following some tutorials on rationalizing materials and blendshapes, etc. I don't make models, but I do need to modify some I've gotten from asset stores for my Unity project.

I have a model with far too many shapekeys which I don't exactly need (when I exported from daz, all shapekeys apply to every single mesh... I don't need shapekeys to change the character's face in his shirt, but I do need the shape keys to change the shirt's wind direction)
So is there a way I can select multiple shape keys and delete them at once, or do I have to delete all of them one by one? (I can't seem to find an option to select multiple, and the only other option is to delete ALL shape keys)

My second question, when porting the model to unity, I see its bone rotations and scales to crazy values. I keep seeing everybody saying "press A to select all, and then just press ctrl+a and select apply rotation & scale" however... nothing happens. I still get the crazy rotation values in unity. I did notice a popup dialogue on the bottom left side of the view in blender, I don't know if I have to do anything else (there's no confirmation box, or anything at all). They say it's the equivalent of "Freeze" in Maya (but I don't have maya lol).

I would appreciate any help I can get!